# Instruction does not dominate all uses despite being the first one in a function

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am generating the following LLVM IR Code:

```
define linkonce fastcc i32 @main() {
  %1 = call i35 @calc()
  %2 = call i35 @calc.1()
  %3 = trunc i35 %2 to i32
  ret i32 %3
}

define private fastcc i35 @calc() {
  %s.ptr = alloca i35, align 8
  store i35 -17179869184, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  store i35 4294967297, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  %s = load i35, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  ret i35 %s
}

define private fastcc i35 @calc.1() {
  %s.ptr = alloca i35, align 8
  store i35 -17179869184, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  store i35 4294967297, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  %s = load i35, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
  ret i35 %s
}
```

I'm also running a verifier pass on the generated module:

```
legacy::FunctionPassManager fp_manager(&module);
fp_manager.add(createVerifierPass());
fp_manager.doInitialization();
for(Function& f : module.getFunctionList())
    fp_manager.run(f);
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %s.ptr = alloca i35, align 8
  store i35 4294967297, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
  %s.ptr = alloca i35, align 8
  %s = load i35, i35* %s.ptr, align 8
in function calc.1
```

But I don't see any problem in my LLVM IR. Also running `lli` on it works just fine.

Does anybody have an idea where the problem is?

---

Note: the error does not occur, when there is only one function

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, probably the two instructions belong to your two different functions. For example maybe `%s.ptr` from `@calc.1` is used by `store i35 -17179869184, i35* %s.ptr, align 8` in `@calc`. Then it wouldn't dominate.

Comment: I thought of that too. Then I renamed both registers to have unique names but the error persisted. So that does not seem to be the cause. But thanks for your idea anyway.

Comment: OK! Next idea: make sure your LLVM build has assertions enabled? (Can be Release+Asserts, but not Release or Debug.)

Comment: I didn't built LLVM myselfe, I just downloaded what was in my distributions repos. But I triggered a lot of assertions  while using LLVM, so I would think that they are enabled. But unfortunately no assertion is triggered in this example.

Comment: I also noticed, that when I comment out `fp_manager.add(createVerifierPass());` it segfaults when compiling the module to an object file. Heres the code for it: https://pastebin.com/wx9NGEA2. Woult it be halpful if I provided the stacktrace?

Comment: Yes it might give us a clue, but it's not uncommon for the backend to crash on IR on which the verifier fails. You might want to check for yourself, verify that a) both functions have one BasicBlock and that the pointers are different b) that I->getParent() on each instruction in each basic block is that basic block, c) that getOperand() results in either a Constant or another value in the same BB. For the constants, check that they're in the same module. The verifier is on about *something* we just need to figure out a result which fits the observed facts.